# Install Ubuntu from USB over Windows partition

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

My Windows install got really broken and I'd like to just overwrite the whole disk with Ubuntu (I've taken the data I needed off the disk). I have Ubuntu running on a live USB but it can only see the 64GB USB and not the 1TB disk. GParted:

[image]

There seems to be some sub-partitioning going on that I'm not sure how to work with:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1
Disk /dev/sda1: 58.47 GiB, 62773657600 bytes, 122604800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1p1      3224498923 3657370039  432871117 206.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda1p2      3272020941 5225480974 1953460034 931.5G 16 Hidden FAT16
/dev/sda1p3               0          0          0     0B 6f unknown
/dev/sda1p4        50200576  974536369  924335794 440.8G  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

There are no other disks showing, only SDA:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -l
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0    2G  1 loop /rofs
loop1   7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop2   7:2    0  219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop3   7:3    0 64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop4   7:4    0   51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop5   7:5    0 31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
sda     8:0    1 58.5G  0 disk 
sda1    8:1    1 58.5G  0 part /media/win_part
sr0    11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

How can I wipe the disk and create one big Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Usually, the formatting of your disk happens during installation, not before that.  You are in the liveCD demo.  If you start the installation I think you'll be prompted to format the disks pretty early.

Comment: That looks more like the ramdom data that a hybrid iso9660 file system puts as it is not a standard partition table. You need to erase that and create new gpt partitioned drive. Like this: Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive  Then with gparted, under device, create partition advanced, choose gpt not the default msdos (MBR) partitioning. Or use gdisk. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/